# PHP - Remove duplicate values in an array based on a key's value and empty values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following output from a PHP array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
     [set1] => Array ( 
            [link] => xyz.com/def
            [time] => 2016-01-03
    [set2] => Array ( 
            [link] => 
            [time] => ) 
    [set3] => Array ( 
            [link] => 
            [time] => ) 
    ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [set1] => Array ( 
            [link] => xyz.com/123
            [time] => 2016-01-03) 
    [set2] => Array ( 
            [link] => 
            [time] => ) 
    [set3] => Array ( 
            [link] => xyz.com/123
            [time] => 2016-01-03) 
    ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [set1] => Array ( 
            [link] => xyz.com/abc
            [time] => 2015-12-03) 
    [set2] => Array (
            [link] => xyz.com/abc
            [time] => 2016-01-03) 
    [set3] => Array ( 
            [link] => xyz.com/123456
            [time] => 2016-01-03) 
    ) )
```

I would like to eliminate duplicate `[link]` regardless of the `[time]` - then I would like to eliminate the empty `[link]` values such as `[0][set2]`, and finally have an output as follows:

```
[link] => xyz.com/def
[time] => 2016-01-03

[link] => xyz.com/123
[time] => 2016-01-03) 

[link] => xyz.com/abc
[time] => 2015-12-03

[link] => xyz.com/123456
[time] => 2016-01-03
```

This is what I tried:

```
$categoryUrlArray= array_unique(($categoryUrlArray, SORT_REGULAR);
    foreach ($categoryUrlArray as $categoryUrlLevel01) {
        $categoryUrlLevel01= array_unique($categoryUrlLevel01, SORT_REGULAR);
        foreach ($categoryUrlLevel01 as $categoryUrlLevel02) {
            echo $categoryUrlLevel02['link'];
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $categoryUrlLevel02['time'];
            echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that duplicates are not being eliminated and empty values are still showing i.e. there are plenty of line breaks `<br/>` - that is why I know they are not being eliminated.

Comment: Does link has `<br/>` in it?

Comment: No it doesn't I use `<br/>` to make it more user friendly when the result is output.

Answer (score 2):

how about just checking inside the `inner loop` for `blanks` and `duplicates`?  then save them all inside a new variable.  like this

```
$newArr = array();
$links = array();
foreach($categoryUrlArray as $urls){
    foreach($urls as $url){
        if(!empty($url['link']) && !in_array($url['link'],$links)){
            $newArr[] = $url;
            $links[] = $url['link'];
        }
    }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

will result to

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "xyz.com/def"
    ["time"]=>
    string(10) "2016-01-03"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "xyz.com/123"
    ["time"]=>
    string(10) "2016-01-03"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(11) "xyz.com/abc"
    ["time"]=>
    string(10) "2015-12-03"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(14) "xyz.com/123456"
    ["time"]=>
    string(10) "2016-01-03"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to check if link is not blank `!empty($categoryUrlLevel02['link'])`

Below is the modified code:

```
($categoryUrlArray= array_unique(($categoryUrlArray, SORT_REGULAR);
foreach ($categoryUrlArray as $categoryUrlLevel01) {
    $categoryUrlLevel01= array_unique($categoryUrlLevel01, SORT_REGULAR);
    foreach ($categoryUrlLevel01 as $categoryUrlLevel02) {
        if(!empty($categoryUrlLevel02['link']))
        {
            echo $categoryUrlLevel02['link'];
            echo '<br/>';
            echo $categoryUrlLevel02['time'];
            echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for efficiently identifying unique values in your result array is accomplished by assigning temporary keys in the result array and checking `!isset()` for the identifying key (which is the `link` value).  If you don't want to see these redundant/temporary keys in your output, call `array_values()`.

*note, making iterated calls of `in_array()` is certainly more costly in terms of performance versus `isset()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FknvT))

```
$categoryUrlArray = [
    [
        "set1" => ["link" => "xyz.com/def", "time" => "2016-01-03"],
        "set2" => ["link" => "", "time" => ""],
        "set3" => ["link" => "", "time" => ""]
    ],
    [
        "set1" => ["link" => "xyz.com/123", "time" => "2016-01-03"],
        "set2" => ["link" => "", "time" => ""],
        "set3" => ["link" => "xyz.com/123", "time" => "2016-01-03"]
    ],
    [
        "set1" => ["link" => "xyz.com/abc", "time" => "2016-12-03"],
        "set2" => ["link" => "xyz.com/abc", "time" => "2016-01-03"],
        "set3" => ["link" => "xyz.com/123456", "time" => "2016-01-03"]
    ]
];

foreach ($categoryUrlArray as $groups) {
    foreach ($groups as $row) {
        if ($row["link"] && !isset($result[$row["link"]])) {  if "truthy" (not empty) and unique
            $result[$row["link"]] = $row;
        }
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'xyz.com/def',
    'time' => '2016-01-03',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'xyz.com/123',
    'time' => '2016-01-03',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'xyz.com/abc',
    'time' => '2016-12-03',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'link' => 'xyz.com/123456',
    'time' => '2016-01-03',
  ),
)
```